# How to turn collapse on and off with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I search with Laravel from the search box, and when I find it, I type bold and make the background color yellow. If the word I found is in collapse, can I make collapse open? I think I can do it with js. but how?
If there is a word in the search part, css changes like this.

```
$row->textMessage = preg_replace('/(' . $search . ')/i', "<b style='background-color: yellow'>$1</b>",
```

The collapse I want to open is the message section here.

```
<div id="{{'collapse'.$oMessage->id}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                    <p><br>{!! $oMessage->htmlMessage !!}</p>
                                                    <p><br>{!! $oMessage->textMessage !!}</p>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('b.highlighted-text').parents('div.collapse');
$(a).toggleClass('collapse collapse show')
```

It takes the value of class and makes a collapse show. It was very simple 2 lines.